# Webwork problem slope is undefined.

Tags: geometry

The equation of the line that goes through the points $(-4,3)$ and $(-4,9)$  can be written in general form $Ax + By +C=0$ where $A,B,C$ are to be found.

I know $B = 0$ is correct and $x=-4$. I tried $A=1$ and it was incorrect. I also tried $C = 4$ and that was wrong as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Frank. Unfortunately you are not going to learn the problems by guessing. To help you understand, please let us know how you arrived at your choice, and what reasoning you used to get there.

Comment: Thanks , what I did was, -4A + 9B + C =0 - (-4A +3B + C =0), which gave me 6B = 0, thus B = 0. Then -4A  + C = 0, thus C = 4A and A  = A, that was my reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two points that you have *satisfy the equation for your line*. What this means is that your points, when inserted into your equation $Ax+By+C=0$, make the equation true for the values of $A,B$ and $C$ you're looking for.

Therefore, insert the points into the equation. Now you have two equations to work with. Try to see how far you can get from there. You don't have to guess; it can be solved analytically.

---

**EDIT:**

So $B=0$, where can you go from here?

We have $Ax+C=0$. Note that this expression does not depend on $y$. That is, for *any* $y$, the value should be the same. However, $x$ always stays the same, namely $x=-C/A=\text{constant}$. This means we're dealing with a vertical line, as seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot((-4,3),(-4,9))), where I've just plotted a line through the two points (note that the line extends forever in the $+y$ and $-y$-directions).

Comment: @Frank Great, that's correct! Now, how do you interpret this? If you're having trouble doing this, try drawing the line.

Comment: @Frank Did you figure it out? Otherwise let me know. Also, since you're new to the site (and since I have no shame in life :P) I wanted to let you know that if you like an answer, you can upvote and/or "accept" it (the latter is done by pressing the tick below the up/down-vote arrows next to the answer) and make the answerer very happy. Note that you can only accept one answer per question you ask, but (if you have 15 or more reputation) you can upvote as many answers as you want. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks and no I did not, I really hit a wall here if you could help me out further it would me much appreciated .

Comment: @Frank See my edit, hopefully that should shed some light on the situation.

Comment: I still can't figure out why A = 1 and C = 4 is wrong ?

Comment: @Frank It isn't, since $x=-C/A=-4/1=-4$ which exactly where the vertical line is placed. Why do you think this is wrong? Other values of $A$ and $C$ will work as well, as long as $-C/A=-4$.

Comment: Thank you, its because when I put these values in, I get incorrect on Webwork, I believe it is a mistake, I have sent an email and will try to find out.